# Mockito returns Optional.empty instead of object for tests

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Java 18, spring boot starter parent 3.0.4, junit 4.13.2

Debug shows me, that everywhere is the same mock for repository. "Evaluate expression" on `taskRepository.findById(id)` at service method shows that object is null instead of my created `task` object at `init()`.

**Code:**

**TaskRepository extends JpaRepository**

**My service method:**

```
@Transactional
    public Task getTaskById(Integer id){
        Optional<Task> taskById = taskRepository.findById(id);
        if(taskById.isPresent()){
            return taskById.get();
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("Task not found with id : " + id);
    }
```

**My test class:**

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TaskServiceTestWithoutSpring {

    @Mock
    public TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    public TaskService taskService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setId(4);
        task.setStatus(StatusEnum.IN_PROGRESS);
        task.setDescription("amazing task");

        doReturn(Optional.of(task)).when(taskRepository).findById(anyInt());
    }
}
```

I have tried change @Mock by @MockBean, call `when(taskRepository.findById(anyInt())).thenReturn(Optional.of(task));` instead of current code, change `anyInt()` parameter to various mockito parameters

Any advices, please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `@Spy` on the tested service? Don't do that.

Comment: sure, thanks for advice, I will read more about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
when(taskRepository.finById(anyInt()).thenReturn(Optional.of(task))
```

on the test method with annotation @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

to improve your test method, thy this template

```
@Test
void testGetTaskById() {
        // given
        var anyId = 8
        var expected = new Task();
        expected.setId(4);
        expected.setStatus(StatusEnum.IN_PROGRESS);
        expected.setDescription("amazing task");

        // when
        when(taskRepository.finById(anyInt())).thenReturn(Optional.of(expected));

        // then
        Task actual = taskService.findById(8);
        org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(actual)
                .usingRecursiveComparison()
                .isEqualTo(expected);
}
```

Comment: omg, I missclicked and import was org.hunit.Test, I have changed annotation to @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test and it works, tysm!!!!!